# Can we use folder name as artifact id in maven?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

is there a way to use folder name for artifact id? So we dont need to define a special artifact id in pom.xml.

Comment: Can you show the pom? And what you like to achieve?

Comment: show the relevant part of your pom

Comment: i mean something **<artifactId>${nameOfFolderWhichContainsPom}</artifactId>**

Answer (score 0):

The best and standard way is to define everything inside pom.xml.
I doudt there is option for artifact id, as it is main and critical build parameter.
But you can play with finalName

```
    <build>
    <finalName>${some-project-property}</finalName>
```